# Context Indexes To include Special Characters

Tags: database, oracle, indexing, full-text-indexing, database-indexes

I Have table with below structure

`mytable(id number,
name varchar2(100),
department varchar2(100),
description varchar2(100));`

and created context index on description column

`create index myindex on mytable(description)
indextype IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT
parameters(lexer mylex);`

description column contains comma seperated values and when i do the below search it does OR search.

`select * from mytable where contains(description,'aaron,lord')>0;`

it gives the result having description column as aaron or lord.

Answer (score 0):

Use either `\` or `{...}` to [escape accumulate operators](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/text.112/e16593/cqspcl.htm#i1006222).

**Sample schema**

```
--drop table mytable;

create table mytable(id number,
name varchar2(100),
department varchar2(100),
description varchar2(100));

insert into mytable values(1, 'A', 'A', 'aaron,lord');
insert into mytable values(2, 'B', 'B', 'aaron');
insert into mytable values(3, 'C', 'C', 'lord');
commit;

create index myindex on mytable(description)
indextype IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT;
```

**Problem**

By default the comma is treated as an accumlate operator and returns all four rows since they all have either "aaron" or "lord".

```
select description from mytable where contains(description,'aaron,lord')>0;

DESCRIPTION
-----------
aaron,lord
aaron
lord
aaron lord
```

**Solution part 1 - escaping commas**

Escaping the accumulator will prevent the ORing and exclude "aaron" and "lord".  I assume the real query uses a bind variable and is not hard-coded, which is why the queries below use either `REPLACE` or `||` instead of simply modifying the string.

```
select description from mytable where contains(description, replace('aaron,lord', ',', '\,')) > 0;
select description from mytable where contains(description, '{' || 'aaron,lord' || '}') > 0;

DESCRIPTION
-----------
aaron,lord
aaron lord
```

**Solution part 2 - add comma to printjoin**

```
drop index myindex;

begin
    ctx_ddl.create_preference('mylex', 'BASIC_LEXER');
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mylex', 'printjoins', ',');
end;
/

create index myindex on mytable(description)
indextype IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT
parameters ('LEXER mylex');
```

Now only the one row will be returned.

```
select description from mytable where contains(description, replace('aaron,lord', ',', '\,')) > 0;
select description from mytable where contains(description, '{' || 'aaron,lord' || '}') > 0;

DESCRIPTION
-----------
aaron,lord
```

But the results are getting so specific I wonder if it would be better to avoid the `CONTAINS` and just use regular SQL functions and conditions.

Comment: I have used this case                                                                                             `select description from mytable where contains(description, '{' || 'aaron,lord' || '}') > 0;`  it displays the result which have value aaron lord also. Could you please let me know how to avoid this?